# Correct use of format specifier to show up to three decimals if needed, otherwise zero decimals?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, stringwithformat, format-specifiers

I've found %g to show only decimals if needed. If the number is whole, no trailing .000 is added, so thats good.
But in the case of for example 1.12345 I want it to short the answer to 1.123.
And in the case of 1.000 I want to only show 1, as %g already does.

I've tried to specify %.3g in the string, but that doesn't work.
If anyone has the answer, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 11):

I reviewed the abilities of a "format string" via the [IEEE Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) and as I understand it your wished behavior is not possible.

I recommend to you, to use the NSNumberFormatter class. I wrote an example that matches your wished behavior. I hope that helps:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
NSString *example1 = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:123456.1234]];
NSLog(@"%@", example1);
NSString *example2 = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:123456.00]];
NSLog(@"%@", example2);
```

Comment: Jan Weinkauff - Thank you so much! Amazing that there are people around like you, willing to use your own time to find answers for others!

Answer (score 2):

What do you get for NSLog(@"%.3g", 1.12345)?

I did some tests and as I understand your question you're on the right track. These are my results:

```
NSLog(@"%g", 1.000000);    => 1
NSLog(@"%g", 1.123456789);  => 1.12346
NSLog(@"%.1g", 1.123456789);  => 1
NSLog(@"%.2g", 1.123456789);  => 1.1
NSLog(@"%.3g", 1.123456789);  => 1.12
NSLog(@"%.4g", 1.123456789);  => 1.123
```

To get what you want use @"%.4g".

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it still ain't working correctly.

Comment: %.3g wont show semi large numbers, as 100 000. That gets printed as 1E+05, which is not ideal :D

%.3f seems to fit the best, but that always leaves trailing zeros when on a whole number.. :(

Comment: How would I get 123456.1234 printed as 123456.12,
as well as 123456.00 printed as 123456?

Two decimals, only when needed..?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Jan's solution for Swift 4:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ""
let example1 = numberFormatter.string(from: 123456.1234)!
print(example1)
let example2 = numberFormatter.string(from: 123456.00)!
print(example2)
```